# Simplifying parcels to share borders using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, leaflet

Is there a QGIS plugin or other method that simplifies parcels to share a common line(border)?

I'm pretty sure I read about this some time ago. Couldn't find anything here or elsewhere.

I'd like to reduce a parcel shapefile in size to be rendered as a WMS via GeoServer.

I'm using:
PostGIS 1.5
GeoServer 2.3
QGIS master(dev)
Leaflet 0.6.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- QGIS uses shapefiles and shapefiles have no topology. If two areas shared a common border that border is stored in duplicate (store individual geometric objects in isolation).
- GRASS GIS is a topological GIS: the adjacent geographic components in a vector map are related. The common border between two areas exists once and is shared between two areas. When you import a shapefile, it use [v.clean](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html) and [v.build](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.build.html) to clean the shapefile and build the GRASS layer. For using GRASS in QGIS, see [Cleaning of topology of a SHAPE file using the GRASS Toolbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34415/how-to-check-topology-in-qgis).
- PostGIS, **since its version 2.0**, has also a [topology](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgisTopology) and can do the same process, see [Clean Polygon](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCleanPolygons). Problem, your version of PostGIS has no topology ( but you can install an initial implementation of the Topology model support ([Index of /postgis-1.5.3/topology](http://staging.experionglobal.com/postgis-1.5.3/topology/)).
- In the solution of Barret, GeoJSON is like a shapefile (no topology) and TopoJSON has a topology ([TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson)). You can convert a GeoJSON file to a TopoJSON file (see [Convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45138/convert-geojson-to-topojson)) or a shapefile to a TopoJSON file ([Command Line Reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference))
- Leaflet can use TopoJSON files (see [D3 Geodata Basics – A Map Overlay can have many Faces](http://www.digital-geography.com/d3-geodata-basics-a-map-overlay-can-have-many-faces/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=d3-geodata-basics-a-map-overlay-can-have-many-faces))
- GeoServer can use GeoJSON files ([How do I get GeoJSON data from GeoServer into show up on my Leaflet map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/how-do-i-get-geojson-data-from-geoserver-into-show-up-on-my-leaflet-map)) but not yet TopoJSON.
- PostGIS can import GeoJSON files but not yet TopoJSON.

So, for me,  the solution would be to upgrade PostGIS, import the shapefile in PostgreSQL/PostGIS, clean it and create a topology, and serve the resulting layer with GeoServer.

Answer (score -1):

This might be an interesting rabbit hole to run down:

[TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson)

Here are some blurbs: [Difference between GeoJSON and TopoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740705/difference-between-geojson-and-topojson) and [How is TopoJSON different than GeoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/what-is-topojson-and-how-is-it-different-than-geojson)

And possible real-world usability. If you can convert from TopoJSON to GeoJSON, then you could [convert from GeoJSON into PostGIS.](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2012-February/032573.html)

All this being said that I have not used either TopoJSON or GeoJSON very much, and not at all in PostGIS. But, it was the first thing that came to mind when I read your question.