# Does GeoPackage support topology?

Tags: topology, geopackage

Does GeoPackage support topology?

I am looking for resources that discuss this topic in more detail.

I googled and did not come across good resources that discuss this question in detail. I could not find informations on this topic in the [official webpage](https://www.geopackage.org/). I do not seem to be the only person who does not find any resources on this topic (see [Seeking alternatives to Geodatabase to describe topological relations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311385)). As I think that it is very important to know weather or not this format supports topology, I consider it to be an important question. Especially, since geopackage are considered to be an alternative for shapefile and latter is often criticized for not supporting topology.

Comment: [This post](https://www.gis-blog.com/geopackage-vs-shapefile/) lists "No ability to store topologies in the files" as a con of the shapefile format in a direct comparison between the shapefile and geopackage formats, which strongly implies that geopackages support topology.

Comment: Just trust the specification http://www.geopackage.org/spec/ which does not say anything about topology. By now GeoPackage supports just common simple feature geometries. However, GeoPackage is using SQLite as database and it is possible to use additional tables for storing the topology rules so making it to support topologies is possible. Meanwhile you can use SpatiaLite http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/topology-preview.pdf.